# How to insert multiples records with pymssql

Tags: python, pymssql

I want to insert  Pandas dataframe to MS SQL table. I know that there is `.to_sql()` method but we don't use SQLAlchemy here. Before that we used `cursor.executemany()` but it just runs INSERT many times and it is very slow.

So I made a function that works but I don`t like it. I want to use iterators and generators to increase memory utilization (because we will have a big amount of records) but it doesn`t work for me I need any advice on how to improve it

```
def tranche(tranche_size, iterable):
return (islice(iterable, start, start + tranche_size) for start in range(0, len(iterable), tranche_size))    

def insert_dataframe(table_name, df, chunk_size=100000):
dtype_map = {​​​​
    np.dtype('O'): '%s',
    np.dtype('float64'): '%d',
    np.dtype('int64'): '%d',
}​​​​
columns = ', '.join(df.columns.tolist())
values = df.values.tolist()
dtypes_base = [dtype_map.get(dtype, '%d') for dtype in df.dtypes]
dtypes_base = ['(' + ', '.join(dtypes_base) + ')']

for sub_values in list(tranche(chunk_size, values)):
    sub_values = tuple(sub_values)
    tmp_list = tuple(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, sub_values))
    dtypes = ', '.join(dtypes_base * len(sub_values))
    insert_statement = "insert into {​​​​table_name}​​​​ ({​​​​columns}​​​​) values {​​​​dtypes}​​​​".format(table_name=table_name,
                                                                                     columns=columns,
                                                                                     dtypes=dtypes)
    with get_cursor_to_db as cursor:
        cursor.execute(insert_statement, tmp_list)
    pass
return
```

BTW

- python 2.7.10
- pandas 0.19
- pymssql 2.1.5

Thanks

UPD with `executemany()` it was like

```
def insert_data_frame_to_table(data_set, table_name):
dtypes = ['%s' if dtype == 'O' else '%d' for dtype in data_set.dtypes.tolist()]
insert_statement = "insert into {​​​​​​​table_name}​​​​​​​ ({​​​​​​​columns}​​​​​​​) values ({​​​​​​​dtypes}​​​​​​​)"
values = [tuple(statement) for statement in data_set.values.tolist()]
insert_kwargs = {​​​​​​​
    'table_name': table_name,
    'columns': ','.join(tuple(data_set.columns)),
    'dtypes': ','.join(dtypes)
}​​​​​​​
query = insert_statement.format(**(insert_kwargs​​​​​​))
with get_cursor_to_db() as cursor:
    cursor.executemany(query, values)
```

Comment: Can you share the code where you have used executemany ?

Comment: @DeepakTripathi Sure I added it to main post.